# DOM Exception 5 when using atob function

Tags: javascript, base64, decode

I wrote a function that will encode and decode every 5 characters of a string to/from Base64. The encode one works perfectly, but the decode doesn't. The console said:

```
INVALID_CHARACTER_ERROR: DOM Exception 5
```

I have tried [this](http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/07/20/utf-8-in-javascript.html) but it doesn't help me.

How can I make it works properly?

Thanks,

[JSbin](http://www.jsbin.com/toneta/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you decode from base64 to string, the normal procedure is that it will take 4 characters from the base64 string and convert it to 3 bytes. If you pass 5 characters to the atob() function, it will throw an exception, as the number of characters passed should be a multiple of 4. [Here](http://jsbin.com/gegunurujo/1/edit?js,console) is a link to my solution. For more information on Base64 decoding, you can refer this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).